# If $X$ is a compact topological space and if some sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous functions separates points on $X$, then $X$ is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

I have a little problem with this Theorem 3.8 c) If $X$ is a compact topological space and if some sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous functions separates points on $X$, then $X$ is metrizable.

The big deal is that in the proof Rudin constructs a metric $d(x, y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|$, and this metric induces a topology denoted by $\tau_{d}$ and I have to prove that $\tau_{d}\subseteq \tau$ so in order to do that I must take a basic $B_r(x) \in \tau_{d}$ and prove that there exists an open set $U \in \tau$ such that $U\subseteq B_r(x)$ but I don't know exactly how to do it, may you give any hint please? I'm really stuck.

I just have some ideas with weak topology but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: You need uniform boundedness of $f_n$'s.Otherwise $d$ may not be  a metric.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy easily fixed y taking $d(x,y)= \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}\min(|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|,1)$ instead. Not an essential flaw. The sum then converges absolutely and uniformly (and so is continuous by standard facts).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Of course, I know how to fix that. But if you find a mistake you should point it out before posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $d$ is continuous as a function on $X \times X$, $\tau_d \subseteq \tau$ is immediate:

$B_r(x)=(d_x)^{-1}[(-\infty,r)]$ where (for any fixed $x$) the map $d_x: y \to d(x,y)$ is continuous from $X$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Old folklore fact from my generalised metric spaces period: continuous metric function implies submetrisable...

Comment: Thank you so much, just in order to be sure that i understood correctly, is inmediatly because the map $d_x$ is continuous, and that map is continous because is the metric with a fix point, am i right?

Comment: @sigma7541 yes, it's easy to see that if $d$ is continuous, so are all $d_x$...

Comment: Thank you again, i didn't have any idea! thank you so much!

Comment: @sigma7541 Hope it opens your eyes to new proof ideas..